# Self Join table to identify new records by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that updates daily with new invoice lines by date. However, each new day will contain ALL of the invoices from the previous days. 1-1-2017 will contain all invoices as of 1-1-2017, but 1-2-2017 will contain all new invoices as well as the invoices from 1-1-2017. Here is an example below.

[image]

I want to be able to show just the new records that appear on 3/23/2017. I attempted with this code:

```
    SELECT 
    a.[Date]
    ,b.[Date]
    ,a.[Inv Name]
    ,b.[Inv Name]
    ,a.[amt]
FROM 
    [Invoice Table] a LEFT JOIN 
    [Invoice Table] b ON a.[Inv Name]=b.[Inv Name]
WHERE 
    --a.[customer_industry]<>b.[customer_industry] AND
    a.[Date] = '3/23/2017' AND
    b.[Date] = '3/22/2017' AND
    b.[Date] = IS NULL
```

When I run this, I get zero results. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, represent dates using ISO standard formats.  Second, when using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on all but the first table go in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `NULL` values in non-matching rows get filtered out.  Also, `= IS NULL` is not valid syntax.

I think you intend:

```
SELECT a.[Date], b.[Date], a.[Inv Name], b.[Inv Name], a.[amt]
FROM  [Invoice Table] a LEFT JOIN 
      [Invoice Table] b
      ON a.[Inv Name] = b.[Inv Name] AND b.[Date] = '2017-03-22'
WHERE  --a.[customer_industry]<>b.[customer_industry] AND
      a.[Date] = '2017-03-23' AND
      b.[Date] IS NULL;
```

However, I think this is much more simply written using `LAG()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(date) over (partition by [Inv Name] order by date) as prev_date
      from [Invoice Table] t
     ) t
where date = '2017-03-23' and (prev_date is null or prev_date <> '2017-03-22')
```

Comment: Thank you sir, can you elaborate on your WHERE clause from your first code snippet? It looks like you have two of them, did you mean to put a.[date] = '2017-03-23' and b.[date] IS NULL in the same clause with an AND statement?

Comment: @raidboss . . . The intention is `AND`.

Comment: Do you mind further explaining why the NULL values in non matching rows will be filtered out if I don't put conditions for the second table in the ON clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    a.[Date]
    ,b.[Date]
    ,a.[Inv Name]
    ,b.[Inv Name]
    ,a.[amt]
FROM 
    [Invoice Table] a LEFT JOIN 
    [Invoice Table] b ON a.[Inv Name]=b.[Inv Name]
where b.[Inv Name] Is null
```